# Randomizing the order of questions within a Mechanical Turk HIT

Tags: mechanicalturk

I've created a HIT that contains a bunch rather typical survey questions. I want every worker to answer all of the questions, but I want to have the order that the questions are presented in be randomized. Is this possible is in a standard QuestionForm HIT?

Answer (score 0):

No.

You'll need to use [`ExternalQuestion`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_ExternalQuestionArticle.html) for this along with some serverside script that randomizes the questions.

Comment: This could also be done, although less elegantly, using javascript in an HTMLQuestion HIT.